# unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android error while using pinch/zoom for Appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I was trying to open selenium.org and click on project tab but the object was not identifiable(even using uiautomator until the page was zoomed).Hence also trying to zoom so that object is identifiable. But zoom is not functioning.Is there some other way that i can find the element.

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class OpenBrowser {

    private AppiumDriver <WebElement> AndDriver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "TA9330416L");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.1");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "org.chromium.chrome.browser.document.ChromeLauncherActivity");
        AndDriver = new AndroidDriver <WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        AndDriver.quit();//Always quit your driver
    }

    @Test
    public void launchWebsite()throws InterruptedException {
        AndDriver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        AndDriver.pinch(323,323);
        AndDriver.findElement(By.name("Projects")).click();

    }
}


/*

FAILED: launchWebsite
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: operation is unsupported on Android
  (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.76)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.18.343845 (73dd713ba7fbfb73cbb514e62641d8c96a94682a),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 18 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35'
System info: host: 'USHYDPTHAKURI1', ip: '10.14.225.155', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
*/
```

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 1):

With capabilities you provided you will get Chromium as application, not browser. So, there is no method 'get' for this application.